# Unable to control hero / hero getting deselected

Tags: dota-2

So I have a couple of problems that I only recently have begun to experience in Dota 2:

1.Sometimes, the hero gets deselected, without me pressing anything or clicking anywhere. This is often but not always accompanied by loss of sound; the music and any other source of sound just get muted. Once I select my hero again, the sounds and music is resumed.

2.This one is a relatively new one. Sometimes, when I tell my hero to move somewhere, it won't move. It is selected, and I can see everything else thats going on (so it's not like I've lost connection). And I can even buy stuff in the Shop. The only problem is that my hero won't move. I have not yet checked if it can cast spells when this happens. Disconnecting and then reconnecting solves the problem, but obviously it still is a problem.

I have a hunch that it has something to do with my network and/or connection to the server, but while I do sometimes experience lag or a slow connection, it is pretty good most of the time, and the problems above do not necessarily occur when I have a bad connection.

Comment: 1. sounds like dota-window is getting out of focus - might be another process is fetching the clicks. 2. might be related - mayber another programm is open at the spot where you mainly want to move? - Try clicking the outer edges of the screen for a test

Comment: Have you tried verifying integrity of your games cache? I have problems with dota 2 all the time easiest option is to verify integrity of cache and check to see if all dota 2 files ahve been installed properly.

Comment: @Shaeldon I don't think any of those is the case, mainly because the only program I had running was Dota 2, and if the Dota window is getting out of focus, shouldn't I be able to not do anything?

Comment: @PythonNovice I haven't. How do I do that?

Comment: @SaintSix_ Load Steam. > From the Library section, right-click on the game and select Properties from the menu. > Select the Local files tab and click the Verify integrity of game cache... button.
Steam will verify the game's files - this process may take several minutes.

Comment: I had a simmilar issue, and it turned ou that it was the "back" mouse button(2 sidebuttons Deathadder mouse)  that got STUCK, and kept pressing all time. Since the hardware was broken, i had to blacklist that button disabling it on the mouse utility...

Comment: @WizLiz Thanks, I tried that but it says "Integrity successfully validated" which I take to mean that there isn't any issue with the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd download [**Malware Bytes**](http://filehippo.com/download_malwarebytes_anti_malware/download/a9a03ca37d2011a674e0df4a406b972a/) and run a scan on your computer.
Sounds like something is making the game window lose focus, I'm going to assume you are running it in full screen. If not, try that.

as for number 2, that sounds like network issues / Lag.
Had it happen to me before when I was playing on a 200KB/s connection.
Have a look and see what the other players are doing when this happens, if they are all moving in a completely straight line without changing direction even when hitting objects then you've definitely dropped out.
You said that you can see everything that is going on though so maybe this is not the case. The first fix might fix the 2nd.

Give it a shot.

Comment: Running a scan detected 1019 threats. Dang. I'd think having Norton would give me some protection at least :P Anyways, the threats are eliminated, and hopefully that will resolve the issue. Since I can't really induce the problems on my own, I'll accept this answer if the problems don't persist; might take a day or so. Thanks :)

Comment: Wow man, that's a new record! No problem, and Good Luck!